# suspend-then-hibernate after some delay from lightdm

Tags: systemd, suspend, hibernate

I have a laptop with Arch Linux, lightdm 1.30.0, and JWM v2.4.2. I want my system to do the following:

1. Suspend and lock the screen after 10 minutes of inactivity.
2. Then hibernate after 30 minutes of inactivity.

To do this, I try to use xautolock and systemd suspend-and-hibernate: xautolock is launched by JWM as `xautolock -time 10 -locker "systemctl suspend-then-hibernate" -notify 60 -notifier "notify-send -u critical \"The computer will be suspended in 1 minute\" -t 5000" &`. In `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` I have `HibernateDelaySec=1800`. I also have `light-locker --lock-on-suspend` running.

However, I have 2 problems:

1. Firstly, I noticed that after 10 minutes the laptop suspends as expected, but then after some time (less than 30 minutes) it wakes up and shows the lightdm login screen. This prevents it from hibernating in time. I have no idea why it wakes up and what to do about it.
2. Secondly, of course, xautolock does not start and run before login, so the system is never suspended from the login screen. I don't know how to make it do this and ask for your advice on this.